# Why IF statement become false , If I write a name present in the nested list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

When I input "Ali" it jumps to new user statement. Anyone please explain me why?

```
Data_base = [["Ali","1234","5000"],["Sara","1234","2000"]]
User_name = input("Enter your name")
if User_name in Data_base:
  print("User persent")
elif User_name not in Data_base:
  print("New User")
  New_User_name = input("Your name: ")
  Data_base.append(New_User_name)
  print(Data_base)
```

Comment: `"Ali"` is a string, and your list contains only lists. A string is never equal to a list, hence it's not present.

Comment: Thank you, Silvio Mayolo

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your list is made up of two separate lists.

```
Data_base = [["Ali","1234","5000"],["Sara","1234","2000"]]
```

So when you check if the input is in the list, Python checks if any of the internal values are equal to the input. i.e.:

```
input = ["Ali","1234","5000"] or input = ["Sara","1234","2000"]
```

By grouping it into a list I assume the second and third values belong to the first value. Instead of the list I would suggest using a `dictionary`:

```
Data_base = {"Ali" : ["1234","5000"], "Sara" : ["1234","2000"]}
```

And then, for checking:

```
if User_name in Data_base:
    print("User persent")
else:
    # Do whatever
```

Comment: If you're using a dictionary then you shouldn't iterate over it to find a key, just look up the key instead, or use `name in db` to check if it's there.